# Authorize.NET - SIM integration - Error 13

Tags: payment, authorize.net, unauthorized

I have inherited an MVC application that is integrated with Authorize.NET to pass user to their SIM solution to process payment.  I am in the process of refactoring the application and I am reusing the "Transaction Key and Fingerprint Hash" logic to send a transaction request.

I am using my client's Merchant Account Login Key and Transaction Key to send a test transaction request to the https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll sandbox environment and I receive the following error:

> Error 13: The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account
>   is inactive

Does my client's merchant account need to be configured to allow test transactions?  Or do I need to create separate Authorize.Net SIm credentials to test sandbox transaction request?

Any other Authorize.Net configurations that I should focus?

Answer (score 1):

The URL you are hitting only works for specific test accounts (i.e developer accounts). Using actual Authorize.Net production account credentials will not work in the test environment. If you want to test their specific account you will need to use the production URL and set it to test mode to do your testing.

If you are just doing dev work and want to make sure your code works correctly you should [register for a developer account](https://developer.authorize.net/hello_world/sandbox/) and then you can use that test URL for testing.

Comment: I have created a sandbox account with Authorize.net.  Got my API Login ID and created a Transaction Key and tried to connect to https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll and got a "(97) This transaction cannot be accepted" error

Comment: See: https://support.authorize.net/s/article/Error-97-This-transaction-cannot-be-accepted